# Every open set is a countable union of compact sets. [In which kind of topological spaces this is true]

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space.

Under which hypotheses on $X$ every open subset can be written as a union of countably many compact sets. I was wondering if $\sigma$-locally compact is a sufficient condition and, more generally, if there exists a characterization of this kind of topological spaces.

Comment: If the space $X$ is separable and locally compact, for example. Do you need weaker conditions?

Comment: Under your hypotheses I can find an exhaustion, right? This is too much. I do not need an increasing sequence. Anyhow, it is not something that I need; it is more something that I am trying to explore more in detail.

Comment: @ajotatxe separable and locally compact won't be enough. E.g. consider $\beta \mathbb{N}$ e.g.

Comment: I guess he meant completely separable (i.e., second countable).

Comment: second countable seems like overkill.

Comment: $\sigma$-compact perfectly normal spaces. A space is perfectly normal if every open set is $F_\sigma$,

Comment: Perfect, $\sigma$-compact and perfectly normal is what I was looking for. Actually, I think that the correct setting is $\sigma$-compact $G_\delta$ space.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That $X$ is $\sigma$-locally compact (by definition: both locally compact and $\sigma$-compact) is not enough, as shown by an example like $\beta \mathbb{N}$, the Čech-Stone compactification of the integers, which is moreover separable. I think $I^I$ is an example too, BTW.

If every open set is $\sigma$-compact (hence Lindelöf) it means that $X$ must be itself $\sigma$-compact, hereditarily Lindelöf and also perfectly normal. And having those properties plus local compactness implies that every open set is $\sigma$-compact. But without that we have spaces like $\mathbb{Q}$ which is obeys what you want but is not locally compact.

So there is a characterisation within the class of locally compact Hausdorff spaces (namely equivalent to being hereditarily Lindelöf), but in general I'm not so sure. There are hereditarily Lindelöf Hausdorff spaces that don't obey your property, like the space of irrationals $\mathbb{P}$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ of course, homeomorphic to $\omega^\omega$). We need enough compact subsets, but a countable Hausdorff space like $\mathbb{Q}$ automatically satisfies it, without having that many compact subsets.